# Does Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) have any viable competitors for doing multi-core projects?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

This is a question asked out of curiosity. GCD has always struck me as being very cool. When I first saw it, it looked too good to be true! It's basically how easy it is to use that makes it so beautiful. Just create a C block and throw it in a queue and the OS takes care of the rest!

However, I'm wondering: Is there anything better than this available out there on other platforms? If I were to make a naive guess, it would seem to me that this would not be the case, because no other company than Apple seems to have that much control over both OS and hardware. It would seem to me that on all other platforms you would be forced to manually hand-tune stuff (such as number of threads to create, number of cores, etc.) that you don't have to do with GCD. Would my guesses be right?

Final curiosity question:

Why didn't the crowd cheer (as the Apple crowds usually do) when Apple introduced GCD in the Snow Leopard WWDC keynote? Is it because people just weren't that much familiar with multicore stuff? Or is it because it isn't really that fancy or unique after all?

Comment: Would be nice if we could wiki this for discussion :)

Comment: @Perception: No, it wouldn't. Stack Overflow is not intended for "discussion" type questions. The FAQ makes this pretty clear. Although we do have a chat room if you'd like to carry on an extended discussion that doesn't fit our targeted Q&A format.

Comment: @Cody - I agree, and already flagged the question as such. It is an interesting question nonetheless. If not kept on SO it would be nice to see it moved to one of the other stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely... my top main option: http://www.erlang.org. This language make multi-core/multi-machine processing as easy as other languages do a for loop ;)...  Probably the most used alternative for this kind of task....